# I want to know if it’s correct using this phrase ‘’ what is wrong about it ?’’

Tags: phrases

Please is it correct to use this phrase ‘’ What is wrong about it?’’

l’m from Ghana and l adapted a way of speaking our language called ‘Twi’ and one of my brothers were like why do l always mix speaking ‘Twi with English??’ , so l replied saying what is wrong about it?… so l wanted to know if it’s right to use that phrase

Comment: Hello Henry.  What is your doubt and uncertainty about this phrase.  What context will you use it in? Why do you think it is might be wrong? Why do you think it might be right?  There's nothing wrong with those words, in the right context.  Indeed I might ask you "What is wrong about it?"  But "What's wrong *with* it?" may be better in some contexts

Comment: Okay , l’m from Ghana and l adapted a way of speaking our language called ‘Twi’ and one of my brothers were like why do l always mix speaking ‘Twi with English??’ , so l replied saying what is wrong about it?… so l wanted to know if it’s right to use that phrase

Comment: Thanks for your comment Henry.  I now understand how you used the phrase.  Can you also explain why you doubt it's right to use the phrase?  Did your brothers understand you? Did they tell you that the English is wrong. Did they suggest an alternative?

Comment: By the way, you have a habit of using lower case "ell"  for capital "I" (i)  These look similar in some fonts, but they are different.  If you write "l am happy", it will look strange if the font changes, because that is "L AM HAPPY"

Answer (score 0):

There's no big error, but it would be better to use "What's wrong with it?".

However there are thousands of examples, in a simple google search, of native speakers of English using "about".  So "about" is also correct, with the same meaning.